# Displaying query results when using table aliases

Tags: laravel

I have a select script that displays team names and the match results, the script looks like this ->

```
select match.ID, match.ht_ID, ht.Name as ht_Name, match.at_ID, at.Name as at_Name, match_results.Results 
from match_results
join match on mattch.ID = match_results.Match_ID 
join teams ht on match.ht_ID = ht.ID
join teams at on mtach.at_ID = at.ID`
```

My Laravel controller has this function:

```
 DB::table('results')
        ->select('match.ID', ht.Name', 'at.Name', 'results.Results')
        ->join('match','match.ID','=','results.Match_ID')
        ->join('teams as ht','match.ht_ID','=','ht.ID')
        ->join('teams as at','match.at_ID','=','at.ID')
        ->get();
        return view('results',['result' => $result]);
```

My blade:

```
@foreach($result as $results)
<tr>
        
        <td> {{$results->ID}} </td>
        <td> {{$results->ht.Name}} </td>
        <td> {{$results->at.Name}} </td>
        <td> {{$results->Rezultats}} </td>
       
</tr>
@endforeach
```

How can I code it so ht.Name is replaced by the home team name and at.Name is replace by the away team name?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```php
->select('match.ID', 'ht.Name as home_team_name', 'at.Name as away_team_name', 'results.Results')
```